# JpaPagingItemReader could not extract ResultSet

Tags: oracle, jpa, spring-batch

This is my configuration job class

```
   @Configuration  
   @EnableBatchProcessing  
   @Import(CacheConfiguration.class)

    public class ProductConfiguration {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Inject
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Inject
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
```

Reader

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<Product> productReader() throws Exception {
    JpaPagingItemReader<Product> reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<Product>();
    reader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory());
    reader.setQueryString("select p from Product p");
    reader.setPageSize(1);
    reader.afterPropertiesSet();
    return reader;
}
```

Processor

```
@Bean
public ProductProcessor productProcessor() {
    return new ProductProcessor ();
}
```

Writter

```
@Bean
public ProductWritter productWritter() {
    return new ProductWritter();
}
```

Step

```
@Bean
public Step productInitialStep() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("initialStep")
            .<Product, ProductData> chunk(10)
                .reader(productReader())
                .processor(productProcessor())
                .writer(productWritter())
            .build();
}
```

Job

```
@Bean
public Job productJob() throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("productJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(productInitialStep())
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

}

And when run the app I have following errors in Reader step:
`Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`
`Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Any idea for I get this errors ? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see why this is happening. We have a test similar to your setup which is passing: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaPagingItemReaderCommonTests.java#L31 (even with pagesize=1). Would this be related to Oracle? Have you tried the same code with H2 or another db?

Comment: I use oracle 11g and the query syntax is not recognized, I think this is my problem

Answer (score 0):

The SQL string is invalid.   This

> "select p from Product p"

Should be something like

> "select * from Product p"